# Laravel 5.2 not recognizing cross-domain jQuery method as AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.2 is not recognizing request as AJAX from cross-domain jQuery load() method:

jQuery from site one:

```
 $('#results').load('http://site2.com/test');
```

Controller method on site two:

```
 public function myMethod(Request $request)
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

        if (!$request->ajax()) {
            abort(403, 'Invalid Request');
        }
          // do something
    }
```

The request is received and has no issues other than not being recognized as an AJAX request. The load() method called from the same domain IS recognized as AJAX.

Any ideas?

Comment: I though you cannot do this unless due to security issues/restraints in jQuery. You have to use other alternatives to get the request to fully function properly like "CORS". I do not know much about CORS request though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CORS middleware file that includes "X-Requested-With" as an allowed header:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization'
        ];

        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);
        return $response;
    }
```

Replace the jQuery load() method with ajax() and add an 'X-Requested-With' header to the jQuery AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'http://site2.com/test',
     headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
     success: function (data)
        {
           //do something
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's HTTP Request class extends Symfony's, which checks the request's X-Requested-With header is set to 'XMLHttpRequest'. This header isn't sent in cross-domain requests with jQuery by default, unless you disable its cross-domain protection:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/',
    crossDomain: false
});
```